# Take out enum to configuration file

Tags: c++, enums

For providing correct drawing order I use simple enumerator:

```
enum class DisplayLayer
{
    background,
    // Below a lot of different layers dedicated to particular item types
    itemTypeA,
    itemTypeB,
    //..
    itemTypeZ,
    effects
}
```

Each drawing object know his own `DisplayLayer` (sometimes more than one) and before drawing, all objects collected in `std::vector` and sorted in order of `DisplayLayer` and additional attributes.
This simple mechanism worked properly, but rarely it demands some updates: adding new levels, remove some old ones and reordered them. When layers count was moderate it was easy to check all relative drawings, but now it contains 50+ layers and after each change drawing should be checked carefully. If QA missed some cases it leads to drawing issues. No way to fixed it with patches, only rebuild executable file.

Now I think to take out `DisplayLayer` enum to config file, like `.xml` or `.json`. It will allow making patches without rebuilding binary file and additional flexibility in debug time.
Config may contain simply key-value pairs.

Question is which data structures I should use for better solution and performance.
For example, is it a good idea to keep layer Ids as set of string constants, like this:

```
const std::string DISP_LAYER_BACKGROUND = "background";
const std::string DISP_LAYER_ITEM_TYPE_A = "itemTypeA";
const std::string DISP_LAYER_ITEM_TYPE_B = "itemTypeB";
...
```

And in config parser consistently use them to extract sort values form configuration file and fill `std::map<std::string, int>`, where key is `LayerId` and value is corresponded sort layer's value.
In this case each drawing objects would consist `std::string` data field instead of `DisplayLayer`, but before drawing it would demand a lot of appeals to our map for converting `layerName` to layer sorting order.

Thanks in advance for every idea how take out enumerator from code to config file and solve my particular problem.

Comment: Have you tried to `std::unordered_map<std::string,DisplayLayer>` ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried any approaches yet. But conceptually it seems like using std::map with O(1) complexity.

Comment: yep, when std::map (red-black tree) have `O(log n)` complexity.